# Click on image as Button?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<img src="/images/ic_highlight_removegray.svg" alt="">
</button>
```

I have tried click this pop up (X)image, which is link. I have done this with all possible selectors including Xpath, class & cssSelectors but no result. Please suggest is this a special case of image/button.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Thread.sleep(35000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='share_preview_modal']/div/div[1]/button")).click();
```

I also tried same with wait, relative & absolute xpath, .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);  - failure

```
    <div id="share_preview_modal" class="modal fade pro_info_member in dashboard-modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="user_profile" style="display: block;">
<div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
<div class="modal-header">
<div class="preview-header">
<span class="success-msg white_box_info" style="display:none">Restricted email access to domains </span>
<button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<img src="http://some-url/images/ic_highlight_removegray.svg" alt="">
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-content white-popup " style="background-image: url("");">
<!-- white popoup -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try the following xpath : `//img[@src='/images/ic_highlight_removegray.svg']`

Comment: `//button[@class='close'][@data-dismiss='modal'][@aria-label='Close']`

Comment: Thanks for quick response 'Kishan', but shared xpath are also not working.

Comment: What error you are getting? Please share a screenshot inspecting the close button

Comment: Can you share the error which you get while trying to click?

Comment: No compile time error, code runs but stops at this last statement. Which is meant to close the pop up. org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: You want to click on image or button?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath to click on Close button:

- *xpath 1*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[id='share_preview_modal']//button[@class='close']")).click();
  ```
- *xpath 2*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='share_preview_modal']//button[@class='close']")).click();
  ```
- *xpath 3*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[*id='share_preview_modal']//button[@class='close']")).click();
  ```

Comment: same xPath i got from firebug at beginning but this also didn't work.

Comment: @AshishKumar can you get me some more of the relevant HTML DOM?

Comment: Your xpath will not work here, You have not close double quote properly. `("//button[@class='close']")`

Comment: Right 'Jainish' sir, i tried with correct syntax as well.

Comment: @AshishKumar can you try with the updated answer and update me. Thanks.

Comment: @Dev I tried with new xpath you provided but still not working. The feature i am automating is working fine manually. But no idea why same is not functioning with Selenium. Tough luck this time. Is something wrong with HTML?

Comment: @AshishKumar nothing wrong with HTML, problem is we need to identify the unique xpath of the element. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @Dev I also tried with your new xPath written didn't work.

Comment: @AshishKumar try with the first option in the updated answer.

Comment: This is not working, i will try this with interface JavascriptExecutor.

Answer (score -1):

With Selenium 3, method "click" has some problems. If this method doesn't work, you can try :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[*id='share_preview_modal']//button[@class='close']")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Comment: OP have mentioned that he already tried `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)`

Comment: Agree with @Andersson